# Join in Dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe

Joining two dataframe

df1 =

```
Customer_id Month   Weightage_Pos
    76    April       1.4
    76   February     1.4
    76   January      1.4
    76  June          1.4
    76  March         1.4
    76  May           1.4
    106 April         1.4
    106 June          1.4
    106 May           1.4
    177 June          1.4
    212 May           1.4
    313 May           1.4
    580 April         1.4
    580 February      1.4
    732 January       1.4
    861 April          2
```

Another dataframe df2 =

```
Customer_id Month   Weightage_Available_Balance Credit_Card_Weightage   Inflow_Weightage    Final_weightage
76  April   2   0   0.15    2.15
76  February    0   0   1.8 1.8
76  January 0   0   0.15    0.15
76  June    2   0   0   2
76  March   1.8 0   2.1 3.9
76  May 2   0   0.15    2.15
106 April   2   0   0   2
106 February    2   0   0.45    2.45
106 January 0   0   0   0
106 June    2   0   0   2
106 March   2   0   0.45    2.45
106 May 2   0   0   2
119 April   0   0   0.3 0.3
119 March   0   0   0.15    0.15
119 May 0   0   2.4 2.4
177 June    1.8 1.2 0.15    3.15
177 May     0.8 1.2 0   2
198 February    0   0   0.45    0.45
198 June    0.8 0   0.45    1.25
198 March   0   0   1.2 1.2
313 April   0.8 0   0.15    0.95
313 March   0.8 0   0   0.8
313 May 0.8 0   0   0.8
397 May 0   0   0   0
547 February    0   0   0.15    0.15
547 May 0   0   0.3 0.3
```

I write code as :

```
final_data_frame = pd.merge(df2,df1,on= ['Customer_id','Month'],how='left)
```

But the output of final_data_frame is not correct as it shows all column values as NAN values in df2 with additional column Weightage_pos

how can this issue be resolved.Is above join method wrong

Comment: `df1.merge(df2,on= ['Customer_id','Month'],how='left')` any difference?

Comment: @mad_  this works